# Freeradius 3, OpenLDAP Cisco AV Pair

Tags: authentication, openldap, freeradius, radius

Migrating from Freeradius 1.x to 3.2
The user database is on OpenLDAP and the radius server is used to authenticate shell login to Cisco and other network devices. It's not for WiFi or EAP authentication.

On LDAP, the ldiff for network administrators have these entries:

```
radiusServiceType: 6
radiusReplyItem: Cisco-AVPair = "shell:priv-lvl=15"
```

On freeradius 1, there's a config file ldap.attrmap with the followin entries, among others:

```
replyItem       $GENERIC$                       radiusReplyItem
replyItem       Service-Type                    radiusServiceType
```

On freeradius 3.2 config: mods-available/ldap:

```
ldap {
  update {
                reply:Service-Type              := 'radiusServiceType'
...
```

What is the correct way of generating a response containing 'Cisco-AVPair'?
Like this (from Freeradius 1.x):

```
Received Access-Accept Id {...} length xxx
    Service-Type = Administrative-User
    Cisco-AVPair = "shell:priv-lvl=15"
```

I realize that $GENERIC$ might not longer work so I'm open to LDAP schema changes.

This works, but adding an entry for $GENERIC$ generates an error:

```
rlm_ldap: libldap vendor: OpenLDAP, version: 20513
   accounting {
    reference = "%{tolower:type.%{Acct-Status-Type}}"
   }
   post-auth {
    reference = "."
   }
/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ldap[136]: Failed parsing attribute reference
/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ldap[136]: reply:$GENERIC$
/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ldap[136]:       ^ Unexpected text after unknown attr
/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ldap[8]: Instantiation failed for module "ldap"
```

authenticationopenldapfreeradiusradius